# Error in creating array variable in Debian 8.4

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a very basic shell script containing

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME[0]="Hello"
echo ${NAME[0]}
```

So when I run this script an error occurs stating

```
./test.sh: 2: ./test.sh: NAME[0]=Hello: not found
./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: Bad substitution
```

So basically I looked through a few tutorials and found this to be the basic way to declare arrays. So I am confused as to why this is an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You're running `/bin/sh`, If that shell is in fact bash, calling it by that name puts it in POSIX compatibility mode, where there are no arrays.  Use shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead.

Comment: @ghoti IMHO answer already contained this info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting your script as `#!/bin/sh`, which has a soft link to `dash` (The current version of sh which conforms with the *POSIX 1003.2 and 1003.2a* specifications for the shell) and `dash` doesn't support arrays. In debian 8 onwards `dash` has become default shell, so if you run `ls -la /bin/sh` the output will be `/bin/sh -> dash`

However bash still remains the default login shell, only the default /bin/sh used in shell scripts has been changed. So if you run your code on terminal, it will work just fine. More information on why this switch was made in Ubuntu can be found [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/).

If you want to use arrays in your script then you must start your script with `#!/bin/bash`

So your script works perfectly if modified like this

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME[0]="Hello"
echo ${NAME[0]}
```

**More information on Dash as Sh** [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: It worked, thanks! Can i also consider bash as the default shell since I didnt install it? It was already there when I installed the os.

Comment: @Patrick bash remains the default login shell, only the default /bin/sh used in shell scripts has been changed, more information can be found [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/)